# NullPointerException When Intent is used Android After Checking A boolean Condition?

Tags: android, button, android-intent, nullpointerexception, boolean-logic

I have a activity am using a boolean condition to check some thing .if the boolean condition Satisfy i need to Go to The next Page. But When The condition Satisfy the Device get crash With `NullPointerException` Am giving The Code Below

The Boolean Condition

```
 boolean check()
{

    boolean matches=false;
    int falseFlag=0;
    if(cc.length==picarray.length)
    {
        for (int i=0;i<cc.length;i++)
        {
            if(cc[i].equals(picarray[i]))  
            {

                //---The Database Value Stored in Array is modified---

                xmin=X[i]-25;
                xmax=X[i]+25;
                ymin=Y[i]-25;
                ymax=Y[i]+25;

                //---Check Whether The Selected Password Is Inside The Array Values---

                if(xmin<realx[i]&&realx[i]<xmax)
                {
                    System.out.println("TRUE");
                }
                else
                {
                    falseFlag++;
                    System.out.println("FALSE");

                }
                if(ymin<realy[i]&&realy[i]<ymax)
                {

                    System.out.println("TRUE");
                }
                else
                {
                    falseFlag++;
                    System.out.println("FALSE");

                }

            }
            else
            {
                falseFlag++;
            }



        }

    }
    else
    {
        falseFlag++;
    }
    if(falseFlag==0)
    {
        matches=true;
    }
    System.out.println("Authentication returns "+matches);
    return matches;

}
```

in button click

```
 b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

  if(check())
                {
                    Intent sa=new Intent(Test.class,Test2.class);
                                    startActivity(sa);
                    System.out.println("U R AUTHENTICATED");


                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("INVALID USER");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "INVALID USER", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

    }
    });
```

Comment: Which line throws the NullpointerException? - post a stack trace if possible

Comment: Can you post the Exception StackTrace ? there are no issue in this code unless you are not defined the Test2 activity in the manifest or you are trying to use a null context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this,

```
Intent sa=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Test2.class);
```

basically intent needs context and not a class...

i doub't this `(Intent sa=new Intent(Test.class,Test2.class);)` will compile

Answer (score 1):

The first argument is a `Context` so when you create the intent, it should be:

> Intent sa=new Intent(Test.**this**,Test2.class);

instead of

> Intent sa=new Intent(Test.**class**,Test2.class);

This should also work:

> Intent sa=new Intent(v.getContext(),Test2.class);

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent sa=new Intent(Test.class,Test2.class);
```

The first parameter should be `Test.this`(Context), is it not throwing a Compile-time error ??